# .NET Entity Framework Core 6 - problem with relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have models Person, DocIdent, Participant and Subject.
A person can have a collection of DocIdent objects. For example, John have both a passport (with value xxxx) and a Social Security number (with value yyyy).
A person can participate in a Subject, and it will do so with ONE of its DocIdents.

With models defined as shown below, when I create a new migration and try to update-database, it throws error:

***Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint FK_Participants_Persons_IdPerson' on table 'Participants' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.***

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    //nav. props
    public virtual ICollection<DocIdent> DocsIdent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Participant> Participants { get; set; }
}
    
    
    
public class DocIdent {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int IdPerson { get; set; }       //FK
    
    [ForeignKey("DocIdentType")]
    public int IdDocIdentType { get; set; }       //FK
    
    //nav. props
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual DocIdentType DocIdentType { get; set; }
}
    
    
    
public class Participant {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("Subject")]
    public int IdSubject { get; set; }       //FK
    
    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int IdPerson { get; set; }       //FK
    
    [ForeignKey("DocIdent")]
    public int IdDocIdent { get; set; }       //FK
    
    
    //nav. props
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual DocIdent DocIdent { get; set; }
}
    
    
    
public class Subject {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    //nav. props
    public virtual ICollection<Participant> Participants { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can just [configure this behavior](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Data/MintPlayerContext.cs#L138-L139)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I was doing it wrong and have finally found the correct way to do it:

Instead of trying to define a relationship in Participant model to both Person and DocIdent, I have dropped completely the relationship between Participant and Person, and (as a DocIdent can only be related to a single person), I can always get to the person through the DocIdent.

So for example, if I have a participant, to get its DocIdent I would just do participant.docident as expected, and to get the person, I would do participant.docident.person.

Doing it this way, I get no error and as said, I can get to the person from the Participant so its all good.